# SQL to have dates from different tables appear in chronological order by column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to query dates from three different tables and order each date chronologically into columns. Each table Event1, Event2, and Event3 contains event dates that are to occur chronologically for any one individual (i.e. Event1 should occur before Event2 which should then occur before Event3). But it just so happens that a person has a date for Event1 that is after Event2 and Event3. I would like to get a result set that shows two rows. One row that shows the earlier events from Event2 and Event3 and a second row that contains only the newer event date from Event1. Below are the data for this example:

**Main**

```
ID
----------
Person001
Person002
Person003
Person004
Person005
```

**Event1**

```
ID        | EVENT_DATE
----------+-----------
Person001 | 2019-04-30
Person002 | 2018-02-01
Person004 | 2018-05-01
```

**Event2**

```
ID        | EVENT_DATE
----------+-----------
Person001 | 2005-03-03
Person002 | 2018-03-15
Person003 | 2017-10-10
Person005 | 2018-10-01
```

**Event3**

```
ID        | EVENT_DATE
----------+-----------
Person001 | 2005-04-15
Person002 | 2019-01-10
Person004 | 2018-12-11
Person005 | 2018-12-15
Person005 | 2019-07-02
```

I would like the results set to appear like this:

```
ID        | EVENT_DATE_1 | EVENT_DATE_2 | EVENT_DATE_3
----------+--------------+--------------+--------------
Person001 | NULL         | 2005-03-03   | 2005-04-15
Person001 | 2019-04-30   | NULL         | NULL
Person002 | 2018-02-01   | 2018-03-15   | 2019-01-10
Person003 | NULL         | 2017-10-10   | NULL
Person004 | 2018-05-01   | NULL         | 2018-12-11
Person005 | NULL         | 2018-10-01   | 2018-12-15
Person005 | NULL         | NULL         | 2019-07-02
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

I should clarify: Person001 is just an example individual. I would like to query a whole database of people. For most people, the events will fall in the correct order. However, some people will have multiple instances of an event. For example, someone can have two Event1 dates. For Person001 in the example, they are supposed to have an Event1 date that corresponds with Event2 and Event3; it just happens to be missing data.

Edit: I added more example data. I tried the code in the answers and it seems to work only for the case of Person001. If there are other arrangements of data points, it doesn't seem to work. I'm hoping the extra persons will account for other types of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit strange but you can do:

```
select id, event_date as event_date_1, null as event_date_2, null as event_date_3
from event1
union all
select coalesce(e2.id, e3.id), null, e2.event_date, e3.event_date
from event2 e2 full join
     event3 e3
     on e2.id = e3.id
order by id, event_date_1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8801bc0565cc783e751239ee2c9292c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to work only for Person001. I tried it on other data and it doesn't work as well. I edited the original post to contain more example data.

Comment: I checked the db<>fiddle, Person002 should have all their event dates on the same row because the dates are in the correct chronological order. Your code puts Event1 dates on a new row for all ID's if an Event1 date exists.